# Delete repeating elements across sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

I have a list like this

```
test = {{1, 3, 5}, {7, 2, 8, 5}, {7, 1, 3}};
```

The list is guaranteed to have duplicates only across sublists and not within.
I would like to remove elements from the sublists which appear more than once across all sublists. One of the lists needs to retain the element, preferably a random one. Empty lists should be preserved. The expected results would be:

```
RandomRemoveUniques[test]
{{1, 3 }, { 2, 8, 5}, {7}};

RandomRemoveUniques[test]
{{1}, { 7,2, 8, 5}, {3}};

RandomRemoveUniques[test]
{{1,3}, {7, 2, 8, 5}, {}};
```

I am looking for an efficient solution (as possible) as these list will be fairly large and the function will be called several times.

I can get as far as counting the number of duplicates

```
count = Counts@Flatten@test
<|1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 5 -> 2, 7 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 8 -> 1|>
```

and then I can use `DeleteCases[]` but I don't know how to satisfy the other two requirements.

Comment: I can't test at the moment, but try this: `ReplacePart[test, Flatten[Values[If[Length[#] == 1, Nothing, Complement[#, {RandomChoice[#]}]] & /@ Merge[Flatten[MapIndexed[Rule, test, {2}]], Identity]], 1] -> Nothing]`

Comment: Beautiful, looks like it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 7):

You may use a pattern approach with `ReplaceRepeated` using `RandomChoice` and `Nothing` to randomly delete the duplicates between the sublists.

```
randomRemoveUniques[list_] :=
 list //.
  {s___, {s1___, x_, e1___}, m___, {s2___, x_, e2___}, e___} :>
   With[{pos = RandomChoice[{True, False}]},
    {s, {s1, If[pos, x, Nothing], e1}, 
     m, {s2, If[! pos, x, Nothing], e2}, e}
    ]
```

With `test` as in OP of five example runs.

```
SeedRandom[3221]
Table[randomRemoveUniques[test], 5] // Column
```

> ```
> {{},{2,8,5},{7,1,3}}
> {{1,5},{7,2,8},{3}}
> {{1,5},{2,8},{7,3}}
> {{},{7,2,8,5},{1,3}}
> {{3,5},{2,8},{7,1}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice pattern matching.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

My original answer worked by flattening the list, finding all positions of each number, deleted one of those positions, then set the remaining positions to `Inactive[Nothing]`, repartitioned the list to it's original form, and then activated the list. The speed bottleneck was deleting a representative from each class since it used [`RandomInteger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger) as many times as there were sublists.

My update instead uses one [`RandomReal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal) call to determine which position to remove from each set of positions, and is about twice as fast:

```
rru2[list_]:=Module[{flat = Flatten@list, pi, lens, p, keep, remove},
    pi = PositionIndex @ flat;
    p = Values @ pi;
    lens = Length /@ p;
    keep = Accumulate[lens] - Floor[RandomReal[1, Length[lens]] lens];
    remove = Flatten[p][[Complement[Range @ Length @ flat, keep]]];
    flat[[remove]] = Inactive[Nothing];
    Activate @ TakeList[flat, Length /@ list]
]
```

Comparison using @JEM_Mosig's test data:

```
test3 = DeleteDuplicates /@ Split[RandomInteger[{1,8000},10000], RandomChoice[{0.8,0.2}->{True,False}]&];

rru2[test3]; //RepeatedTiming
rru[test3]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.015, Null}
>
> {0.029, Null}

**Original answer**

Here is one idea:

```
rru[list_]:=Module[{flat = Flatten@list, pi},
    pi = PositionIndex @ flat;
    flat[[Flatten @ Values @ Map[deleteRandom] @ pi]] = Inactive[Nothing];
    Activate @ TakeList[flat, Length/@list]
]

deleteRandom[a_] := Delete[a, RandomInteger[{1,Length[a]}]]
```

Here is a run of 100 applications of `rru`:

```
Tally @ Table[rru[test], {100}] //Column //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{\{\{1\},\{7,2,8,5\},\{3\}\},8\} \\
>  \{\{\{1\},\{2,8,5\},\{7,3\}\},7\} \\
>  \{\{\{1,5\},\{7,2,8\},\{3\}\},11\} \\
>  \{\{\{1,3,5\},\{2,8\},\{7\}\},8\} \\
>  \{\{\{5\},\{2,8\},\{7,1,3\}\},3\} \\
>  \left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 5 \\
>  2 & 8 \\
>  7 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),10\right\} \\
>  \{\{\{5\},\{7,2,8\},\{1,3\}\},5\} \\
>  \{\{\{1,3,5\},\{7,2,8\},\{\}\},6\} \\
>  \{\{\{3\},\{2,8,5\},\{7,1\}\},9\} \\
>  \{\{\{1,3\},\{7,2,8,5\},\{\}\},5\} \\
>  \{\{\{\},\{2,8,5\},\{7,1,3\}\},6\} \\
>  \{\{\{3\},\{7,2,8,5\},\{1\}\},5\} \\
>  \{\{\{3,5\},\{7,2,8\},\{1\}\},5\} \\
>  \{\{\{1,3\},\{2,8,5\},\{7\}\},6\} \\
>  \left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  3 & 5 \\
>  2 & 8 \\
>  7 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),4\right\} \\
>  \{\{\{\},\{7,2,8,5\},\{1,3\}\},2\} \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: Don't you mean `Flatten@list` instead of `Flatten@test`?

Comment: @JEM_Mosig Thanks, fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a recursive algorithm:

```
ClearAll[randomRemoveDuplicatesJEMM];
randomRemoveDuplicatesJEMM[sets_List, toDelete_:Alternatives[]] := 
Catch[
  Module[{n = Length[sets], i, newSets},
    (* delete all elements that match toDelete *)
    newSets = DeleteCases[sets, toDelete, Infinity];

    (* if only one left, then return the only remaining set *)
    If[n == 1, Throw[newSets]];

    (* randomly pick one of the sets *)
    i = RandomInteger[{1, n}];

    (* recursively assemble the list *)
    Insert[
      randomRemoveDuplicatesJEMM[Delete[newSets, i], Alternatives@@newSets[[i]]],
      newSets[[i]],
      i
    ]
  ]
]
```

To test the algorithms I use three test sets (note the automatic method to generate `test2` and `test3`):

```
test1 = {{1, 3, 5}, {7, 2, 8, 5}, {7, 1, 3}};

test2 = DeleteDuplicates /@ Split[RandomInteger[{1,800},1000], RandomChoice[{0.8,0.2}->{True,False}]&];

test3 = DeleteDuplicates /@ Split[RandomInteger[{1,8000},10000], RandomChoice[{0.8,0.2}->{True,False}]&];
```

For the third test my algorithm requires the setting `$RecursionLimit = 10000`
which you may implement locally using `Block`.

I have also implemented the other algorithms that were suggested and checked the timings on Mathemaitca 11.0:

```
First@RepeatedTiming[randomRemoveDuplicatesJEMM[#]] & /@ 
  {test1, test2, test3}
(* {0.00010, 0.016, 1.13} *)

First@RepeatedTiming[randomRemoveDuplicatesMGOLDBERG[#]] & /@ 
  {test1, test2}
(* {0.00018, 0.0698} *)

First@RepeatedTiming[randomRemoveDuplicatesEDMUND[#]] & /@ 
  {test1}
(* {0.00018} *)

First@RepeatedTiming[randomRemoveDuplicatesJM[#]] & /@ 
  {test1, test2, test3}
(* {0.00012, 0.00814, 0.094} *)

First@RepeatedTiming[randomRemoveDuplicatesCARLWOLL[#]] & /@ 
  {test1, test2, test3}
(* {0.00013, 0.0055, 0.0581} *)

First@RepeatedTiming[randomRemoveDuplicatesANJANKUMAR[#]] & /@ 
  {test1, test2}
(* {0.0000776, 0.37} *)
```

When a test case is ommitted, then the algorithm takes more than 5 seconds to complete. I have replaced `TakeList` by `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` in Carl Woll's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167675/35390), to make it compatible with version 11.0, as he suggested.

In conclusion, in Version 11.0, Carl Woll's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167675/35390) performes best, shortly followed by the answer given in J.M.'s comment. For short lists, though, Anjan Kumar's answer is faster.

Comment: In versions before 11.2 you can use ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` instead of `TakeList`.

Comment: @CarlWoll: nice! Now it works! I'll add this to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my effort. I found the problem was made more difficult than I first thought by the requirement that it must be able to generate cases where one or more of the final lists may is empty.

```
randomDeleteDups[a : {{___Integer} ..}] :=
  Module[{ints, where, retain, rules},
    ints = Union @@ a;
    where = Position[a, #] & /@ ints;
    retain = SplitBy[Sort[RandomChoice /@ where], First];
    rules =
      ({#[[1, 1]] -> #[[All, 2]]} & /@ retain // Catenate) /. 
        HoldPattern[i_ -> l_] -> HoldPattern[i -> a[[i]][[l]]];
    ReplacePart[ConstantArray[{}, Length @ a], rules // ReleaseHold]]
```

#### Tests

```
test1 = {{1, 3, 5}, {7, 2, 8, 5}, {7, 1, 3}};

SeedRandom[1]; randomDeleteDups[test1]
```

> `{{5}, {2, 8}, {7, 1, 3}}`

Tests that which generate empty lists.

```
 SeedRandom[5]; randomDeleteDups[test1]
```

> `{{1, 3, 5}, {7, 2, 8}, {}}`

```
SeedRandom[12]; randomDeleteDups[test1]
```

> `{{1, 3}, {7, 2, 8, 5}, {}}`

```
SeedRandom[15]; randomDeleteDups[test1]
```

> `{{}, {2, 8, 5}, {7, 1, 3}}`

Tests with a bigger list.

```
SeedRandom[1]; 
test2 = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 15}, RandomInteger[{1, 11}]], 5]
```

> ```
> {{5, 1}, {1, 1, 9, 7, 1, 14, 5, 2}, {6, 15, 15, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 13}, 
>  {2, 15, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5, 12, 6, 5, 15}, {1, 2, 4, 14}}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]; randomDeleteDups[test2]
```

> `{{5}, {9, 7, 14}, {6, 2, 4, 13}, {1, 3, 12, 15}, {}}`

```
SeedRandom[3]; randomDeleteDups[test2]
```

> `{{5}, {9, 1}, {6, 15, 4, 3, 13}, {7, 12}, {2, 14}}`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I'll benchmark these tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to randomly generate a pair of positions upon which [`Complement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html)  and [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) can be applied to generate random duplicate free lists.

```
replace[lst_, rule_]:=ReplacePart[lst, #1 -> Complement[lst[[#1]], lst[[#2]]]] & @@ rule;
randomDel[lst_] := Module[{rules, randomRules},
  rules = {#, Reverse[#]} & /@ Subsets[Range[Length[lst]], {2}];
  randomRules = RandomChoice /@ rules;
  Fold[replace, lst, randomRules]
  ]
```

**Test**

```
test = {{1, 3, 5}, {7, 2, 8, 5}, {7, 1, 3}};
Table[randomDel[test], 5] // Column
```

> ```
> {{},{7,2,8,5},{1,3}}
> {{1,3},{7,2,8,5},{}}
> {{1,3},{7,2,8,5},{}}
> {{1,3,5},{2,7,8},{}}
> {{},{7,2,8,5},{1,3}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[deDupe]
deDupe = Module[{f, rs = RandomSample[Range@Length@#]}, 
    f[y_] := (f[y] = Sequence[]; y); (f /@ # & /@ #[[rs]])[[Ordering[rs]]]] &;

SeedRandom[1]
Tally[Table[deDupe @ test, {100000}]] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $$\begin{array}{l}
>  \{\{\{1,3\},\{7,2,8,5\},\{\}\},16679\} \\
>  \{\{\{1,3,5\},\{7,2,8\},\{\}\},16537\} \\
>  \{\{\{1,3,5\},\{2,8\},\{7\}\},16633\} \\
>  \{\{\{5\},\{2,8\},\{7,1,3\}\},16591\} \\
>  \{\{\{\},\{7,2,8,5\},\{1,3\}\},16752\} \\
>  \{\{\{\},\{2,8,5\},\{7,1,3\}\},16808\} \\
> \end{array}$$